# How T4MVC add-in and ASP.NET MVC integrate & work together?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I have an open source ASP.NET MVC application there is an add-in called T4MVC and I can see all the html, aspx, images, Controllers, views  files are integrated, I wonder how it works. 
If I create a file(aspx,html...) has it to be integrated manually to that template(T4MVC) or by default it get mixed? could someone please advise of how to get this(T4MVC) ans MVC do work together since I am new in ASP.net MVC.

Answer (score 3):

T4MVC is a template that Visual Studio will compile and execute when you save the file in the editor (there are tools to automate this; search for AutoTT or Chirpy to check them out).

The template scans your project to find controllers, views, images, etc. and generates code that allows you to reference those items programatically elsewhere in your code. Whenever you add, remove or rename a resource (any of the items the template looks for) the template must be executed again to regenerate the code output.

The advantage of T4MVC (over the use of strings to reference things) is that you get compile-time checking, as well as intellisense and refactoring support.